# clang-format adds extra carriage return every run

Tags: c++, carriage-return, clang-format

I recently ran clang-format on all our source code. I noticed that in some comment blocks, clang-format added carriage returns on every iteration.

They show up as `Cr` when I view them in bitbucket as a diff and `^M` when I do a `cat file.hpp -A`. Right now I have 6 `Cr`s in a file which did not have any before in that line. I am running `clang-format-6.0` on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Any thoughts on why this is going on and how to prevent it from changing every time?

UPDATE: Example from a header block
Here's a piece of text from a header block

```
  /**
  *

  ^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M
  CHANGE HISTORY:
  ^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M

  */
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of this happening?

Comment: You could try `clang-format-7` instead. A lot of bugs have been fixed in it.

Comment: `CR` is line ending used by old Mac (up to version 9), Commodore and so on. Looks like something was incorrectly configured or your file initially didn't used uniform line endings (Windows `CRLF` and Linux/unix `LF`) and as a result some auto detection mechanism in clang-format has failed. Try unify line endings first (preferable by configuring git). Then check options in clang-format.